# Best Practice for refreshing JWT Tokens in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, authentication, jwt

What is the best practice for refreshing JWT Tokens in Xamarin?

We use Jason Web Tokens to login to our API. The tokens expire after some time. As the user should not have to login every time the token expires, the Xamarin app should automatically refresh the tokens in the background. If anything is wrong - for instance the user changed his password on another device - the user should get navigated back to the login page.

Should we use the Task Parallel Library for this?